# Как организовать p2p видео трансляцию на C#?

Tags: c#, json, p2p

Дано:

- 2 клиента с серыми IP-адресами
- сервер- с белым IP-адресом.

Как организовать P2P / (либо через сервер) видео трансляцию на C#, отображая веб камеру пользователя либо его рабочий стол, по типу TeamViewer и демонстрации экрана?